# How can I model and implement course assessments?

Tags: c++, oop, uml, relationship, class-diagram

I´m a bit confused about implementing a program where there exist **students who have courses and teachers who are able to assing grades to each course of each student**.

I was thinking about having a `Course` class which is associated between the `Student` class and `Proffesor` class and, in addition, that `Course` class might have an association class between it and `Student` one:

[image: UMl diagram for my program]

Nevertheless, I think it's wrong because I can't imagine a way to implement that three-part relationship. I tried to find a solution to similar problems but I didn't find anything.

How can I implement it on C++? Or do I have to change my UML model?

Answer (score 2):

In your model, you have binary relation and an association class:

- one-to-many associations can be implemented, using a container of pointers or references to the related objects.
- many-to-many associations can be implemented by having containers on both sides and keeping them in synch (e.g registering a student to a course would add the student on the course side, and the course on the student side.
- many-to-many and association classes can also be implemented using a container object that maintains the connected pairs or the association class instances that point/refer to the connected elements.
- for a professor to reach grades, the trick is to navigate to all the associated courses and find all the related grades that are associated to it
- Last but not least, you can avoid pointers and using instead ids, if your architecture uses registries that store/retrieve objects using a unique identifier
- there are plenty of other ways.

An easy improvement to your diagram is to remove all these unnecessary aggregation diamonds. But the general design seems ok.

Comment: Diamonds are a girl's best friend. And obviously UML teacher's too...

Comment: @qwerty_so I'affraid that... Diamonds are forever, ever and ever... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As opposed to Christophe's statement, your general design is not ok if you need to track which professor has made which assessment. Since in your model, a course has 3 professors, tracking which professor has made which assessment may be required.

In your class model, you would have to replace your `Grade` association class with a class `Assessment` (representing a ternary association class) having a `grade` attribute and (binary) associations with `Student`, `Course` and `Professor`.

After getting your class design model right, you can implement it in the ususal way:

1. Create a C++ class for each UML class.
2. Implement all data attributes as member variables with a suitable data type as their ranges.
3. Implement the `Course`-`Student` and the `Course`-`Professor` associations as reference member variables `students[]: Student*` and `professors[]: Professor*` in the `Course` class.
4. You could implement the `Assessment` class in the form of a member variable `assessments[]: StudentGradeByProfessor*` where `StudentGradeByProfessor` is an auxiliary class with three member variables: `student: Student*`, `professor: Professor*` and `grade: float`.

Comment: It's a valid point of view. However, I did not see the requirement of traceability, and I even had a doubt about about the relation of the rating with the course, since teachers are allowed to assign grades to each student for each course (i.e. not only for their own course), not to speak about the plural of grades (which could  pave the way to several grades for a given course and a given student (like in real life). This being said, I hope you're not recommending an array of native pointers for the C++ implementations, 12 years after C++11 ;-)

Comment: Since a course has 3 professors, it seems important to record which professor has assessed which student. Of course, there needs to be a constraint that only the professors of a course may assess its students. Please give an example of the new type of pointers to be used here (preferably in your answer), as my knowledge of C++ dates back to the 1990s :-)